# python file writing in threads not writing all lines

Tags: python, multithreading

I tested my code output and sort it, but I am not having 0-1999 as expected, lines is missing. Is my code thread unsafe? please suggest how to add thread lock in my code, and i found that my except all doesn't throw any errors, is it correct? thanks

```
import time, threading, random

class MyThreadWithArgs(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, string):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.string = string

    def run(self):
        try:
            fo = open("foo.np2", "a")
            fo.write( self.string )
            fo.write( '\n' )
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.9))
            fo.close()
        except:
            print ("error logging " + self.string)

ttl_threads = 2000
for i in range(ttl_threads):
    t = MyThreadWithArgs(string = str(i))
    t.start()
```

Comment: `except all` does not mean anything special in Python, and the interpreter will choke on it if it has to enter the `except` block. To catch all exceptions, use plain `except`.

Comment: Is this your actual code? `ttl_threads = 2000 for i in range(ttl_threads):` doesn't look like valid syntax to me.

Comment: @Kevin seperate two lines, fixed

Comment: Use `with open(...) as...` to open files. If there is an error in your try block, `fo` will not get closed.

Comment: When I run your code, I get a "too many open files" exception. Perhaps you could open the file once in the main thread, so your other thousands of threads don't have to do it themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably work as expected.  Exception handling removed for simplicity.

```
import time, threading, random

class MyThreadWithArgs(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, string):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.string = string

    def run(self):
        fo.write( self.string + '\n' )
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.9))

fo = open("foo.np2", "a")
ttl_threads = 2000
for i in range(ttl_threads):
    t = MyThreadWithArgs(string = str(i))
    t.start()
```

In the original program, you're opening multiple handles to the same file in append mode.  Each of handles maintains its own pointer to what it thinks is the end of the file, but it's possible for thread-0 to modify the file before thread-1 gets to write.  thread-1 will still write to where the end-of-file *WAS* when it called open.

By keeping only one file descriptor open, you have only one end-of-file pointer and the underlying `write` system call is *probably* reentrant on a given file descriptor via OS internal locking mechanisms.

The other change I made was concatenating the strings from the two calls to `write()` because as two separate calls, you're giving the schedule a chance to switch threads in between system calls, and likely to end up with two `self.string` values in a row followed by two or more `\n` strings in a row.

I don't know off the top of my what (if any) guarantees python makes about `write`, I'm just going off what I know about how `<unistd.h> write()` works in C on most POSIX platforms.  If you want guarantees, check the python documentation, or surround the `write()` call with a lock.

Comment: Brian, great answer. Much better articulated then I could have put it. Quick question -- sake of argument type thing. You make the file handle a global variable (effectively). Could you have also passed in the file handle to the constructor? Or would this pseudo (or actually) clone the reference?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to pass the file descriptor into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time, sys, threading, random

class MyThreadWithArgs(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, i, global_msg_i):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.i = i
        self.global_msg_i = global_msg_i
    def run(self):
        global global_msg
        try:
            i = self.i
            global_msg_i = self.global_msg_i
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.9))
            print (i)
            global_msg[global_msg_i] = str(i)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.9))
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            pass

def reset_threads_global_msg():
    global threads, global_msg, global_msg_i, ttl_threads
    threads = []
    global_msg = [None] * ttl_threads
    global_msg_i = 0

def start_join_threads_write_global_msg():
    global threads, global_msg
    for x in threads:
        x.start()
        time.sleep(0.001) # avoid thread create error when creating too fast?!
    [x.join() for x in threads]
    fo = open("foo_test.np++", "a")
    for msg in global_msg:
        if msg is not None:
            fo.write( msg + '\n')
    fo.close()

ttl_threads = 200
reset_threads_global_msg()
for ttl_threads_i in range(1, ttl_threads + 1):
    t = MyThreadWithArgs(i = ttl_threads_i, global_msg_i = global_msg_i)
    threads.append(t)
    global_msg_i += 1
start_join_threads_write_global_msg()
reset_threads_global_msg()
```